# How to enter data in browse (for a file) dialogue box using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on webpage and using VBA to click on 'Browse' button. 
The functionality is to upload a file. So, when Browse button is clicked the Browse window opens and the file path name has to be entered.

I am copying the name of the path from Excel sheet and trying to paste it into the Browse window.

My problem is that I am unable to paste the file path name into the Browse window.

The line after clicking on the button does not execute till I don't manually intervene and input the path into Browse window .

I want to paste the path name and press enter so that the path is accepted.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<input type = "file" id="Browse_ID"....>
```

My VBA code which is stopping after tagx.Click and waiting for manual input :

```
set ieDoc = ieApp.document
set Tags = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each tagx in Tags

If tagx.ID = "Browse_ID" Then

   'Copy data to be pasted in Browse dialogue box
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet7").Range("D11").Select
   Selection.Copy

   'Click on Browse
   tagx.Click

   'Paste by sending keys control v
   SendKeys "{^v}"

   'Send Enter key so that the path of the file that is entered is accepted and
    'dialogue box closes
   SendKeys "~"

 exit For
 End IF
 Next
```

I tried using Do while, but did not work too:

```
   'Copy data to be pasted in Browse dialogue box
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet7").Range("D11").Select
   Selection.Copy

   Do while (tagx.Click = True)

   'Paste by sending keys control v
   SendKeys "{^v}"

   'Send Enter key so that the path of the file that is entered is accepted and
    'dialogue box closes
   SendKeys "~"
   Loop
```

Please HELP!

Comment: Can you show me the link?

Comment: The site is restricted to only employees of my company. :( I was just checking if there are sites that have similar kind of property. Found one. Not sure what it does. Be careful when u are using it : "http://www.megafileupload.com/". you can use any site that has file upload option and whose HTML code is like the one I mentioned.

Comment: `The page you are looking for cannot be found`

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/

Comment: If I am not wrong then in such a case you will have to use API's. See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/02/02/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window-part-ii/) You have to use a similar logic

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the WebBrowser object directly in Excel...and then use the navigate property..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question :)

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Could you please elaborate it. I do not know how to get the object of the Browse window that pops up when I click on Browse for a file button.

Comment: Hehe, sometimes teach to fish is better than to give the fish... :) Go to the Developer menu - Insert - More Objects - Choose Microsoft WebBrowser

Comment: If your post was correct, I would've been the 1st to upvote it :) 2 reasons why this doesn't answer the question. `1` You are suggesting the user to use ".Navigate" which isn't what the user asked. The problem is that OP is unable to paste file name in the Browse window. `2` When you use a webbrowser & the window opens, it opens modally. That means no code will run till the time you dispose off the window which is again of no use and hence it is imp to create an instance of IE & then use API's to write to the window. See link below OP's Qtn.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47044/discussion-between-crondao-and-siddharth-rout)